# Полноценный эмулятор мобильного браузера

Tags: android, html, css, ios, адаптивная-верстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мой веб-проект на Vue отлично работает в консоле разработчика хрома в режиме эмулятора мобилок. Когда зашёл с реального устройства, половина функционала не работало, как позже выяснилось опера мобайл и андройд мобайл не поддерживают некоторые html тэги или атрибуты.

Существуют ли какие ни будь эмуляторы мобильных браузеров, что бы удобно тестить на работоспособность своё веб-приложение под мобилки.?

Я наткнулся на это https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mobile-emulator/

Но, кажется, этот проект уже давно помер.

Comment: А зачем вы ориентируетесь на устаревшие браузеры, которые давно никто не использует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Genimotion. Вы получите эмуляторы без установки Android Studio овер 10 gb

Answer (score 1):

Гайд по эмулятору Android из Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator

Гайд по эмулятору iOS из Xcode:
https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-use-xcode-ios-simulator-for-responsive-web-testing-on-mac-7870ee4fc22b